# Gradle, use material3 in a compose multiplatform project

Tags: gradle, compose-multiplatform

I'm doing a project with Jetpack Compose Multiplatform Desktop.
I'm not very familiar with Gradle, and I would like to use Material 3 in my project.
So, I added this line in `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14")
```

But when I try to import the lib in a Kotlin file with:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.*
```

I've got an `unresolved reference` issue.

This is my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "18"
                freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
            }
        }
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        jvmArgs += listOf("-Djava.library.path=./lib")
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "FanControl"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I think I should be able to use this lib since the [release note](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/releases/tag/v1.2.1) indicate it support it.

Edit1:
I have this message from Gradle when I try to sync:

```
Could not resolve: androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14
```

Answer (score 10):

Finally found what was the problem, it was the wrong library,
change

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14")
```

with

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.material3:material3-desktop:1.2.1")
```

Comment: To prevent using the wrong version, you can use `implementation(compose.material3)`