# How to use Material 3 Theme and Components in Compose Desktop?

Tags: compose-desktop, material3

I want to use material 3 theme and components in a compose desktop project. I want to achieve the same as the default Empty Activity in an android studio project, where the theme, color scheme, and other components are using material 3 style by default.

After adding the dependencies from the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623364/gradle-use-material3-in-a-compose-multiplatform-project), I managed to import the material 3 component. However, the style used in these components are still using material 2 style.

Here, this is my button and text field.

[image]

This is my build.gradle.kts file :

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
    implementation(compose.material3)
    implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "WebViewApp"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle.kts` file? Also, could you check that you're importing the right button: `import androidx.compose.material3.Button`? Sometimes AS imports the `material.Button` version instead of `material3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @ubertrombone reply, I found out that I imported the wrong package, here is the import prompt and the results :

[image]

It should be the `androidx.compose.material3` instead of `androidx.compose.material`